# Trouble connecting to remote "console session" of a Windows XP pro

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-xp, mstsc

I'm trying to connect to a **Windows XP pro** through **Remote Desktop** (my local machine is on **Windows 7**).

I know that I have to type `mstsc.exe /admin` (I'm not using the deprecated option `/console`) to open the console session.

However, it really seems that I'm not connected to the console session.
For example:

- When I type `echo %SESSIONNAME%`, I get something like `RDP-Tcp#14` instead of `console`.
- When I type `shadow 0` to observe console session, I get `Error [7050]:The requested session cannot be controlled remotely. This may be because the session is disconnected or does not currently have a use
  r logged on.`

By showing process tree with Process Explorer, it looks like the console session is at login screen.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I've not read yet everyting on [this resource](http://www.microsoftnow.com/2008/01/no-more-mstscexe-console.html), but seems to be explaining the problem: it seems that you cannot interact with (logon to) session 0 on a **Windows XP SP3** (or **Vista SP1**, or **Server 2008**)

Comment: Why not use VNC to connect?

Comment: Good idea, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows client OS's only allows one interactive user at a time. When you connect remotely, it locks the console session - hence you finding the console session at the login screen.

If you're not picking up session 0 when logged in remotely then there must be something going on in the background that transfers the console session to your remote desktop when you connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What could be "going in the background" which could prevent me from picking session 0?

Comment: I had a quick Google and found the same page as you. Looks like a security feature.